# C# padding right equivalent in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the following code which is in c# to java. And I am facing difficulty in converting it. Please can anyone suggest me a simple way to do it in Java.

```
 if (Password.Length <= 8)
            Password = Password.PadRight(8);
        else
            Password = Password.PadRight(20);
```

Comment: you can use StringUtils or if your string only contains integer then you can use string format as well by parsing string into inetger

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to modify the methods that are built into the `String` class, so instead I think it's best to write `static` utility methods to reproduce the behaviour of [the C# methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx).

The code might look something like this (though be sure to write your own unit tests before using these methods, or any other methods you write or introduce).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String original = "text";
    int padToLength = 10;
    System.out.println("Padded:\n'" + padRight(original, padToLength) + "'");
    System.out.println("Padded:\n'" + padRight(original, padToLength, '@')
            + "'");
}

public static String padRight(String original, int padToLength) {
    return padRight(original, padToLength, ' ');
}

public static String padRight(String original, int padToLength, char padWith) {
    if (original.length() >= padToLength) {
        return original;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(padToLength);
    sb.append(original);
    for (int i = original.length(); i < padToLength; ++i) {
        sb.append(padWith);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This will output to the console:

```
Padded with spaces:
'text      '
Padded with custom character:
'text@@@@@@'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Apache String util for padding (readymade! solution)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad-java.lang.String-int-

Or you can use string format

`Password = String.format("%20s", Password);` in place of `Password = Password.PadRight(20);`

and 
`Password = String.format("%8s", Password);` in place of `Password = Password.PadRight(8);`